# Query indexed deep links

Tags: android, deep-linking

Is there an api to query deep links that have been indexed in-app? There is an API to index deep links, but I can't find any documentation for querying those indexed deep links.

Here is the google dev example for deep linking:

```
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
...
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  static final Uri APP_URI = Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.android.recipes/http/recipe-app.com/recipes");
  static final Uri WEB_URL = Uri.parse("http://recipe-app.com/recipes/");
  private GoogleApiClient mClient;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ...

    // Connect your client
    mClient.connect();

    // Define a title for your current page, shown in autocompletion UI
    String title = "App Indexing API Title";

    // Construct the Action performed by the user
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(Action.TYPE_VIEW, title, WEB_URL, APP_URI);

    // Call the App Indexing API start method after the view has completely rendered
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mClient, viewAction);
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    ...
    // Call end() and disconnect the client
    String title = "App Indexing API Title";
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(Action.TYPE_VIEW, title, WEB_URL, APP_URI);
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mClient, viewAction);
    mClient.disconnect();
    ...

    super.onStop();
  }
}
```

I don't see any documentation on how to pull those deep links from the googleApiClient.